# redis-py watch hash key

Tags: python, redis

I'm using redis-py to interface with redis through python. I'm in the situation where I need to atomically update a hash key but first need to retrieve the value at that key before I can update it. Looking through the documentation it looks like I can use a pipeline and the WATCH command to determine when a key has changed. Is there anyway to watch a key inside of a hash? or does this only work for singular keys?

Comment: Hello, any solution? I need to atomically update the value of specific hash key as well... The whole hash probably could be watched but the race condition would occur very frequently.

Comment: For singular key i could do it by WATCH and MULTI. But I am also seeking to achieve WATCH key inside a hash key.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot watch hash keys directly, this is not supported by Redis for now. But you can use additional "lock" string keys, and define a contract, by which anyone, who modifies your hash values, should follow the procedure below for any hash key `K`:

1. WATCH `lock:K`
2. HGET K, save current value
3. Start MULTI.
4. SET `lock:K` ""
5. HSET K updated_value
6. EXEC

This will guarantee that the updated hash value is not overwritten concurrently.

Though this is a Python question, I provide a NodeJS function that implements the contract above (just to show an idea):

```
/**
 * Concurrently updates Redis string and hash value under the specified key.
 *
 * @param redisCli Redis client.
 * @param hashName Hash name.
 * @param objId Object ID.
 * @param transFun Cache object transformation function (i.e. a modification that we need to apply).
 * @param cbFun Callback function, to which a modified object is passed in case of success.
 */
exports.redisUpdateHashConcurrently = function(redisCli, hashName, objId, transFun, cbFun) {
    var lockKey = hashName + ':' + objId + ':lock';

    redisCli.watch(lockKey); // Step 1.

    redisCli.hget(hashName, objId, function(err, obj) { // Step 2.
        if (err) {
            redisCli.unwatch();

            cbFun && cbFun(undefined, err);

            return;
        }

        if (obj) {
            var modObj = transFun(JSON.parse(obj));
            var value = JSON.stringify(modObj);

            redisCli.multi() // Step 3.
                .set(lockKey, '') // Step 4.
                .expire(lockKey, 3)
                .hset(hashName, objId, value) // Step 5.
                .exec(function(err, replies) { // Step 6.
                    if (!replies) { // Object was modified by someone else, retry.
                        exports.redisUpdateHashConcurrently(redisCli, hashName, objId, transFun, cbFun);
                    }
                    else { // We have succeeded.
                        cbFun && cbFun(modObj, undefined);
                    }
                });
        }
        else {
            redisCli.unwatch();
        }
    });
};
```

Note that you can specify a TTL for your "lock" keys, so that they are eventually removed.

Comment: You're always writing empty string into `lock:K`, so if this happens concurrently, the value of `lock:K` is NOT updated. Does the `EXEC` still fail in this case? I mean in https://redis.io/topics/transactions it's written as follows "we are asking Redis to perform the transaction only if none of the WATCHed keys were MODIFIED"

Comment: I just tested it. Yes, `EXEC` still fails, even though you are setting `lock:K` to the same value.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [MULTI](http://redis.io/topics/transactions)?  Then you don't need to worry about watching a key inside of a hash (which WATCH does not appear to support, as you suggested).

Comment: It doesn't look like MULTI allows you to retrieve a value, modify it and then set the value back. Unless I'm mistaken MULTI just queues the commands.